# Debian installation has no uucp user - how to create

Tags: debian, exim

I have just installed Debian Squeeze x64 and tried sending myself a test email from it using the normal "mail" command.  When I sent it I got this error from Exim:

2013-06-08 08:12:46 Exim configuration error in line 173 of /var/lib/exim4/config.autogenerated:
  user uucp was not found
Can't send mail: sendmail process failed with error code 1

After a bit of research into this it sounds like all Debian systems should have the "uucp" user, but can I just run "useradd uucp" or does it need setting up to own certain directories and stuff?

Comment: you probably need to `dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config` and select a configuration without uucp support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my Ubuntu system I have a user `uucp` and it must have been created early because of its usernumber. `grep uucp /etc/passwd` gives:

```
uucp:x:10:10:uucp:/var/spool/uucp:/bin/sh
```

and `/var/spool/uucp` does **not** exist. `grep uucp /etc/group` gives:

```
uucp:x:10:
```

and `grep uucp /etc/shadow` gives:

```
uucp:*:15426:0:99999:7:::
```

So you should try to create a new user with:

```
adduser --system --home /var/spool/uucp --no-create-home --shell /bin/sh --group uucp
```

This will give you a user with a 'low' uid, where `useradd uucp` would not.

Comment: useradd uucp and then usermod --home /var/spool/uucp seems to have solved it, thanks

Comment: From the useradd man page:  useradd is a low level utility for adding users. On Debian, administrators should usually use adduser(8) instead. Your command probably got you a 'high' uid. That will work (which is the most important), but is not as clearly a 'system' user as you would get with my example.